# Когда использовать Collection, а когда Iterator?

Tags: java, коллекции, интерфейс

В каких случаях следует идти через Collection, а в каких через Iterator? (особенно если надо просто пробежаться всем элементам). Брюс Эккель в книге "Философия Java" (стр.354) пишет что

> Решение с Iterator выглядит привлекательно при написании класса, в
> котором реали­зация интерфейса Collection затруднена или непрактична.

это и в современной версии Java актуально?

Пример кода:

```
//:holding/InterfaceVsIterator.java
import typeinfo.pets.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InterfaceVsIterator{

public static void display(Iterator<Pet> it){
  while(it.hasNext()){
  Pet p=it.next();
  System.out.print(p.id()+":"+p+"");
  }
 System.out.println();
}

public static void display(Collection<Pet> pets){
for(Pet p:pets)
  System.out.print(p.id()+":"+p+"");
System.out.println();
}
...
```

И почему он назвал класс `InterfaceVsIterator`? `Iterator` ведь тоже интерфейс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

основная разница в том через iterator мы можем вынести поведение обхода коллекции из самой коллекции в отдельный класс и их может быть сколько угодно(реализаций обхода), также реализовать какую-то сложную логику и изменять содержимое коллекции.

```
  List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(integerList, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = integerList.iterator();
    // удалить элементы больше 2
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next() > 2)
           iterator.remove();
    }

    System.out.println(integerList); // вывод [1, 2]
```

хотя сама ide предлагает заменить это всё на лямбду

```
 // удалить элементы больше 2
        integerList.removeIf(integer -> integer > 2);

        System.out.println(integerList); // вывод [1, 2]
```

а вот цикл foreach, там только чтение, нельзя изменять элементы

```
for (Integer integer : integerList) {
    integer++;
}
System.out.println(integerList); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] без изменений
```

можно самому посмотреть разные реализации перебора коллекций в ide, набираешь it
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а насчёт выбора Collection или Iterator, в итераторе 2 метода надо будет переопределить, а в колекшн больше 10. и главный вопрос - зачем свою коллекцию писать?

Comment: Я просто думал что если в новой java есть default, то не надо переопределять всё, достаточно iterator реализовать и всё.

Comment: это без дефолтных методов

Comment: читай будулая (хорсман 1 том) там хорошо описано